# AngularJS can't fetch more than 4 records

Tags: angularjs

*The following code is for an AngularJS code to read data from a .txt file and echo out on the webpage. It works just fine for the entered records in the .txt file, but upon increasing the number of records above 4, the code fails to work. What could be wrong?*

*Index.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular JS Includes</title>
<style>
table, th , td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Roll No</th>
    <th>Percentage</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
      <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>
      <td>{{ student.RollNo }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.Percentage }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<script>
function studentController($scope,$http) {
var url="data.txt";
   $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
                           $scope.students = response;
                        });
}
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

*Data.txt*

```
[
{
"Name" : "Collin James",
"RollNo" : 101,
"Percentage" : "81.5%"
},
{
"Name" : "Michael Ross",
"RollNo" : 201,
"Percentage" : "70%"
},
{
"Name" : "Robert Flare",
"RollNo" : 191,
"Percentage" : "75%"
},
{
"Name" : "Julian Joe",
"RollNo" : 111,
"Percentage" : "77%"
}
]
```

Comment: Are you sure it is because of the number of entries in the file? Could you post an example of Data.txt with some data you tried to add?

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure. I've tried removing entries, and adding entries. Even on the removal of value, the code simply displays the table with the values defined in the <tr>.